# Laravel mutator isn't setting the new value

Tags: laravel, model, mutators

This is an example code which is loaded through a mass job assignment:

```
someModel::create([
    'test' => $data->test
]);
```

In "someModel" i have following mutator:

```
public function setTestAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['test'] = '1234'; //Hash::make($value) instead of 1234 is not working either
}
```

When I run the code, contents of the "test" column in db is not 1234, it's the data that comes from the $data variable. So the mutator is not manipulating the data. Am I missing something basic here?

I have tried to do a dd('test') inside of the setTestAttribute, and it's showing up perfectly, so it is being initialised, it's just not setting/overriding the value.

"Test" column in db is of type: varchar, and test is fillable in the model settings.

Comment: Maybe you will show more your code

Answer (score 0):

Laravel model events and mutators are triggered only with **->save()**.

**->update([...])** and **->create([...])** is for generating SQL "CREATE" and "UPDATE" operations, and they doesn't consider eloquent features.

So (even I also like to use "create" and "update" but for working with mutators) try to use something like this:

```
$someModelInstance = new someModel();
$someModelInstance->test = $data->test;
$someModelInstance->save();
```